# Create ABAP REST Class to query multiple entities

Tags: rest, abap

I don't have Gateway available in my landscape and I want to use the ABAP REST library to expose web services: [SAP Library - REST Programming Tutorial](https://help.sap.com/viewer/753088fc00704d0a80e7fbd6803c8adb/7.52.3/en-US/0f5fb77942744afe94afafa78df57b70.html)

With a very simple example, I successfully created a class to read a single domain list of values, the GET call is quite simple:

`http://mydomain/domainvalues/XFELD`

And the GET implementation is in my class ZCL_REST_DOMAIN_VALUES extending from CL_REST_RESOURCE implementing IF_REST_RESOURCE~GET method.

Now I want to make it possible to read or query multiple domains. I'm not an expert in REST but I've seen two options searching around, one using the same URI as the single entity and one with special URI for queries.

- `http://mydomain/domainvalues?Id=XFELD,WERKS_D`
- `http://mydomain/query/domainvalues?Id=XFELD,WERKS_D`

In the backend, should I use the second approach and create a class only for this call named for instance ZCL_REST_DOMAIN_VALUES_QUERY implementing the GET method again?

Or maybe should I use POST method to send the list of IDs to fetch in the body?

Comment: You are free to choose the way you want. For example you can do like OData (`$filter` in the query string). What advantages do you see in creating a second REST service?

Comment: In OData with SAP Gateway you would have GetEntity and GetEntitySet methods for the "domain" entity. In Gateway the GET request is handled and then directed to the GetEntity if comes with ID or GetEntitySet method if not (or if it's a query with filter). I would like to simulate a simlar behavior with the "raw" rest API but I'm not sure if I can do it with a single class and how should I do it to make it the cleanest possible.

I'm asking what to add to the implementation of CL_REST_HTTP_HANDLER, method if_rest_application~get_root_handler, and if I need one or 2 classes implementing the GET

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks like you know how to solve but unable to choose between the two solutions. Now you know which one is the easiest according to me, and according to Florian. Don't finish like the [Buridan's ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass) :)

Comment: Haha! I didn't know that one, I will remember! Yes I'm a bit like that donkey when I have to decide about a new implementation approach. Especially because this decision will impact the full project that is just starting, so somehow I needed someone to tell me "that's how SAP does it" as in Florian answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAP's own in-house guidelines recommend to shape OData and plain REST services alike, to avoid confusion and facilitate switching between the two:

```
http://mydomain/domainvalues?$filter=Id in ('XFELD', 'WERKS_D')
```

Both would be served by the same REST endpoint handler class, although of course you are free to create separate methods or delegates for the cases.

Remember to sanitize (= whitelist/blacklist/escape) the query parameters before handing them over to some lower level to prevent SQL injection attacks, as @SandraRossi correctly pointed out below.

Comment: @RaTio in the HTTP Request Handler, as you did with `Id`, get the value of `$filter` by ``data(filter_value) = server->request->get_uri_parameter( `$filter` )``

Comment: **Important:** don't pass the `$filter` value directly in `SELECT ... WHERE (filter)` to avoid SQL injection attacks ! You must extract each individual value from the filter list and escape it with something like ``filter = FILTER #( LET filter2 = `0 = 1 ` FOR filter_value IN filter_list NEXT filter2 = filter2 && `OR ID = '` && CL_ABAP_DYN_PRG=>ESCAPE_QUOTES( filter_value ) && `' ` )``

Comment: Added. Always a useful hint. Thanks, Sandra!